# RethinkDB - Polygon Doesn't Accept an Array of Vertices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, geospatial, rethinkdb

I'm really loving that RethinkDB has Geospatial out of the box.

My only issue I'm having is with adding Polygons.

The docs (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/polygon/) says I can only insert my points as arguments. This is completely unrealistic and unusable because I don't know how many vertices my user will decide on their polygon. It would be great if I could throw it an array of vertices but I get the error:

> Unhandled rejection ReqlDriverError: `r.polygon` takes at least 3
>   arguments, 1 provided.

The only thing I can think of doing is making 16 separate functions that take in the specified amount of vertices in an array.

Any ideas what I can do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r.args` to splice an array into a variadic function.  So `r.polygon(r.args(ARRAY_OF_POINTS))` should work.

Comment: wuttttttt!? thanks :D and here I was researching other DB options... lol Thank you!!!!